# Adding strings to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Say that I add 2 users **apple** and **orange** to an arraylist. Then I want to add newton to apple's list of friends. So apple should have 1 friend and orange still doesn't have any friends because I didn't add them yet.

My problem is that when I add newton to apple's friends, newton also shows up in orange's friends. I just need 1 friend to show up for apple and none for orange.

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> users = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();

ArrayList<FacebookUser> recommendedFriends = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();

void friend(String newFriend)
    {
        boolean positiveChecker = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < recommendedFriends.size(); i++) 
        {

            if (recommendedFriends.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(newFriend)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: This friend already exists.");
                positiveChecker = true;
            }

        }
        if (positiveChecker == false) 
        {
            FacebookUser friend = new FacebookUser(newFriend, newFriend );
            recommendedFriends.add(friend);
            System.out.println(friend + " is now your friend.");
        }
        positiveChecker = false;
    }

void listFriends(String allFriends)
    {
         ArrayList<String> usersFriends = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < recommendedFriends.size(); i++) 
            {
                usersFriends.add(recommendedFriends.get(i).toString());
            }
            System.out.println(recommendedFriends);

    }
```

I think it's the way I set up the arraylist for the user's friends, but I'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but `recommendedFriends.get(i).toString() != formerFriend` should be `!recommendedFriends.get(i).toString().equals(formerFriend)`.

Comment: Can you organize your code so that we would understand something? Post only relevant code

Comment: apple's friend? Hmm...

Comment: Edited to make the code more clear. I can add any string as a user and any string I type as a friend. I make 2 users. Then I add a friend to 1 user. The problem I have is that friend shows up as friend for the 2 users, not the 1.

Comment: I don't know whether soul of newton will be happy or not once he will go through your post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that all your friends share one pool of recommendedFriends.  This means that all of apple's friends are also orange's friends as well.

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> users = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();

ArrayList<FacebookUser> recommendedFriends = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();
```

As you can see above, your class contains all the FacebookUser as well as all the recommendedFriends.  You will probably want to put the your list of recommendedFriends in your FacebookUser class so that each user has their own set of friends.

Comment: or use a `Map` (or multimap).

Comment: That's an option too :).